# How is the following ML Curry expression evaluated

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, typing

This question is not homework but it's related to material in a general course I take about programming languages, so I don't know whats the site policy about this

In ML the following expression:

```
fun f x y z = x (y , z) = x (z, y) ;
```

Evaluates to this:

```
val ('a, ''b) f = fn : ('a * 'a -> ''b) -> 'a -> 'a -> bool
```

I understand the type inference done here, but not the structure of the expression returned.

Can someone explain how this works ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused as to what you don't understand. The type of f is a function of three arguments: the first argument is a function of type 'a * 'a -> 'b, and the two other arguments are of type 'a. The result is of type bool. Is this what you don't understand?

Comment: @cody Yeah thats what I don't understand. I understand the first part of `'a * 'a -> ''b` but not the second part ? What's the general approach of understanding this ? How would you convert it to a normal function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that what you are confused about is the common practice of *Curryfication*: the function
$$ (\alpha\times \alpha\rightarrow \beta)\rightarrow \alpha\rightarrow \alpha\rightarrow \mathrm{bool} $$

Is parenthesized as:

$$ (\alpha\times \alpha\rightarrow \beta)\rightarrow (\alpha\rightarrow (\alpha\rightarrow \mathrm{bool})) $$

and is equivalent to a *different* function:
$$ (\alpha\times \alpha\rightarrow \beta)\times \alpha\times \alpha\rightarrow \mathrm{bool} $$

The reason for this is the following. Take a function:

$$f:A \rightarrow (B\rightarrow C)$$
This is a function that takes an element $a:A$ and returns a function
$$ f\ a: B\rightarrow C$$
Apply this to an element $b:B$ and you have
$$f\ a\ b:C$$

It is clear that this is equivalent to a function $f':A\times B\rightarrow C$ that takes a *pair* $(a,b):A\times B$ and returns an element of $C$. The equivalence can be explicitely written:

```
curry : ('a * 'b -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c)
curry f' = function x -> function y -> f' (x,y)
```

or more simply

```
curry f' x y = f' (x,y)
```

The other direction goes:

```
uncurry : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> ('a * 'b -> 'c)
uncurry f = function p -> let (x,y) = p in f x y
```

or simply

```
uncurry f (x,y) = f x y
```